# .htaccess all requests to public except script

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling with the .htaccess files.

My folder structure is as followed:

```
-application
-config
-db
-library
-public
-scrips
-tmp
.htaccess (1)
```

Contents of htaccess 1

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

This works great! However now I'm executing a request to example.com/script/cron.php and it fails because it is redirected public. How can i prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first rule is not needed. `(.*)` will also match the empty string, and therefore `$1` would be replaced with... well... an empty string. To exclude `/script` you need to use a `RewriteCond` like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/script/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```